# Firebase cloud functions deployment issue when using Github package as npm node module

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using github repo tag as npm module in my Firebae cloud functions project and it's working fine in local env.

```json
//package.json
"@instantish/martian": "github:Rakmo33/martian#v2.3.0",
```

However, when I deploy to Firebase cloud functions it throws following error:

```
"Build failed: npm ERR! Error while executing:\nnpm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/Rakmo33/martian.git\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! 
Host key verification failed.\nnpm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights\nnpm ERR! and the repository exists.\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! exited with error code: 128\n\nnpm ERR! 
A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR! /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2021-11-25T10_28_13_554Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know the details of your project, but the fact is if you had executed:

```
npm install git+https://git@github.com/Rakmo33/martian.git#v2.3.0
```

you would have something like this within your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@rakmo33/martian_fork": "git+https://git@github.com/Rakmo33/martian.git#v2.3.0"
  }
```

and you'd have avoided the necessity of using any password-protected SSH keys.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but for me, I needed to `npm uninstall` the dependency first, then reinstall it using the `https://` protocol, and then reinstall `node_modules` locally. Verify in `package-lock.json` that it does indeed use the https protocol, because I think that's what trips up firebase-tools. This was (is?) a [known issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2610#issuecomment-1048117007) in npm 7.